# Configuration changes with git webhook, spring cloud bus and application autorefresh

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-bus

If i have three spring boot applications like Person, Customer, Order with spring.application.name as person, customer, order and each application has configuration in the github Person.yml, Customer.yml, Order.yml. And each application has two instances running like Person1, Person2, Customer1, Customer2, Order1, Order2 and all these are setup to read config from github and also have spring cloud bus dependencies using rabbitmq with which they all subscribe to rabbitmq broker

There is like Spring cloud config server setup to run with Spring cloud bus using rabbitmq and to read config from the above github repository. 
And there is github webhook to the `/monitor` endpoint of the config server.

When i make configuration changes to Person.yml and save it, github will do a post to the `/monitor`endpoint of configserver. And config server will now post those changes to the rabbitmq broker.

At this point since all the applications are subscribing to rabbitmq would all application instances be triggered so that person1, person2, customer1, customer2, order1, order2 will all try to hit the config server and only person1 and person2 will be updated with the changes.
Or only person1 and person2 applications are triggered and they hit config server since changes are only to Person.yml.

Comment: That should be the case. What are you actually seeing?

Comment: So which of the two scenarios would happen (1) all the application instances are triggered and they try to read from config server (2) only person1 and person2 application instances are triggered and only they read from config server?

Comment: `/monitor` tries to imply the service name from the incomming body, for github it should be just person (though having capitol P might break the guessing).

Comment: yeah having capital (P)erson.yml is not working for the autorefresh with rabbitmq and git webhooks. 
But the /refresh endpoing is still working fine.